# Isometries of Hilbert space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, isometries

It is easy to see that for any $x$ and $y$ on the unit sphere of a Hilbert space $H$ there exists a surjective isometry $U$ such that $Ux=y$. Does something more general also hold? That is, given two pairs $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ of vectors on the unit sphere such that $||x_1-x_2||=||y_1-y_2||$, can we find a surjective isometry $U$ such that $Ux_1=y_1$ and $U x_2=y_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For complex scalars, this fails in $\mathbb{C}^2$. Take $x_1 = y_1 = (1,0)$, $x_2 = (i,0)$, $y_2 = (0,1)$. No (complex linear) isometry can take the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $x_1$ and $x_2$ onto the two-dimensional subspace spanned by $y_1$ and $y_2$.

For real scalars, it is true. It suffices to find an isometry from ${\rm span}(x_1,x_2)$ to ${\rm span}(y_1,y_2)$ which takes $x_1$ to $y_1$ and $x_2$ to $y_2$. This just means that you have two points on the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and I have two points on the unit circle, and the distance between your two points equals the distance between my two points, and you want an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to itself that takes your points to mine. Which is easy.

Comment: Well I think your idea for real scalars is the same as mine.

Comment: Yes, it is the same. I mean, I assumed the problem to be obvious in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and you assumed that extending the isometry to the whole Hilbert space was obvious

Comment: Haha, that's right!